# Using polymorphic type in OpenMP reduction

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, openmp, reduction

Here is a "minimal" non-working example of what I'm trying to do.

This code is to compile with `-fopenmp` flag.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void operator() () = 0 ;

    void combine(const A & rhs) {
        // do reduction stuff
        std::cout << "Combine thread : " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void operator() () {
        // do some B specific stuff
        std::cout << "B " ;
    }
} ;

class C: public A {
public:
    void operator() () {
        // do some C specific stuff
        std::cout << "C " ;
    }
} ;

class Computer {
public:
    template<typename B_or_C_type>
    void compute( B_or_C_type & action ) {
        #pragma omp declare reduction (combine_actions : B_or_C_type  : omp_out.combine(omp_in) ) initializer ( omp_priv(omp_orig) )
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(combine_actions : action )
        for( unsigned i =  0; i < 100; ++i ) {
            // do long computation
            action() ;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
} ;

class Manager {
public:
    Manager(Computer * computer) : computer_(computer), action_(NULL)
    {}

    template<typename B_or_C_type>
    void set_action(B_or_C_type * action)
    {
        action_ = action ;
    }

    void run()
    {
        computer_->compute(*action_) ;
    }

private:
    Computer * computer_ ;
    A * action_ ;
} ;


int main() {
    Computer computer;
    B b ;
    C c ;

    // Not working
    Manager manager(&computer) ;
    manager.set_action(&b) ;
    manager.run() ;
    manager.set_action(&c) ;
    manager.run() ;

    //Working
    // computer.compute(b) ;
    // computer.compute(c) ;

    return 0;
}
```

I have 3 types of classes :

- **Actions** : `A` (base class), and `B` and `C` (derived from `A`)
- **Computer** : `Bar` that realize parallel computation (through `compute()` function) using OpenMP and do some actions (from a `B` or `C` class) by calling `operator()`.
- **Manager** : that manages the launching of computation and sets the differents actions.

---

Right now I have this infortunate error that tells me that I `cannot declare variable 'omp_priv' to be of abstract type 'A'`. This is well understandable. My `A` class is in fact abstract, but I wish OpenMP was able to understand that my `A * action_` attribute from `Manager` class is `B` or `C` type. But how could I do that ?

---

The weird thing is that this code works if :

- I bypass the `Manager` class (uncomment working section in `main()`)

or if :

- I renounce to parallelism and comment line 34 / 35 (the ones that starts with `#pragma`)

However, these are not conceivable options.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `A&` doesn't work, but using an `A*` does:

```
B_or_C_type * action_ptr = &action;
#pragma omp declare reduction (combine_actions : B_or_C_type* : omp_out->combine(*omp_in) ) initializer ( omp_priv(omp_orig) )
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(combine_actions : action_ptr )
for( unsigned i =  0; i < 100; ++i ) {
    // do long computation
    (*action_ptr)();
}
```

That way you can skip the whole `B_or_C_type` template thing and just use `A`. As a more crude alternative, you could utilize make a switch for all known subclasses of `A`:

```
void compute( A & action ) {
    B * pb = dynamic_cast<B*>( &action );
    if ( pb ) compute( *pb );
    C * pc = dynamic_cast<C*>( &action );
    if ( pc ) compute( *pc );
}
```

I'm not quite exactly sure why this doesn't work. By the way it compiles with the Intel compiler, but crashes with a pure virtual function call. I would have thought this should do:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction (combine_actions : B_or_C_type& : omp_out->combine(*omp_in) ) initializer ( omp_priv(omp_orig) )
```

But it doesn't. The standard seems a bit vague to me as to what kind of *type name*s are allowed in the *typename-list*. It would seem to me that references are just not correctly supported.